# How to convert milliseconds to display mm:ss in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, string-formatting, time-format

I suppose I need to use StringFormat for this, but I'm out of ideas on how to figure out the format.

Comment: Do you mean you have milliseconds as a number? Can't you change that to a `TimeSpan`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your input value were a TimeSpan or a DateTime, then you could use a simple format string.
But I assume that's not the case.

As far as I know you need to implement your own Converter, which will take your value as an argument, and output a formatted string. 
A standard C formatter can't make actual calculations like modulus which is required to calculate the minutes.

An example: (This code is not checked, but written on the fly!)

```
public class MmSsFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Int32 sss = (Int32)value;
        Int32 ss = sss / 1000;
        Int32 mm = ss / 60;
        ss = ss % 60;
        return string.Format(@"{0:D2}:{1:D2}", mm, ss);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing; // Thanks to Danny Varod for the suggestion!
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now add the namespace to your XAML, to recognize the Converter, then add the Converter as a resource in your XAML.

Then you can bind to the converter, something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Milliseconds, Converter={StaticResource MmSsFormatConverter}}" />
```

Note that you will need to implement that ConvertBack function if you do two-way binding.
And also you can use the **paramater** argument to pass a ConverterParameter, like a format string.

You might want to add type checks and other constraints on the code I wrote. (What about a situation where you will exceed 59:59? Right now it will go to 60:00, and can event go to 123:59)

Comment: Better yet, return Binding.DoNothing in the ConvertBack method.

Comment: And as for the Convert method itself, I went with
TimeSpan length = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(value));
            return length.Minutes + ":" + length.Seconds.ToString("D2");

Comment: You can also use [TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.frommilliseconds.aspx). Argument is of type Double.

Comment: @Kuraj if you are using a TimeSpan, then you do not even need a converter. You can just use a simple string format.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create the converter  you could also do:

```
    <TextBox Height="23" Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat={}{0:mm:ss}}" />
```

Time could be a property in your code behind. Or you can bind it to something else..

[There is more examples in here.](http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/)

Comment: Sorry, but the format string is not correct. 
Correct would be:
<TextBox Height="23" Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat={}{0:mm':'ss}}" />

Comment: Just to add another possibility `StringFormat=\{0:dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt\}`